# column to row in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to pivot one column, in a 2 column result set. For e.g.

[image]

The number of email address per Id can vary. Not sure if PIVOT would work for this requirement.

I cannot use a temp table, only a single select query

Comment: please share sample data as text and expected output as text

Comment: If the number of email addresses, and therefore columns in your expected output, can vary, then you'd probably need dynamic SQL for this.  But more important, what value would you be using to pivot?

Comment: This looks like the typical dynamic pivot or dynamic crosstab to me. There are been hundreds if not thousands of examples of how to do this just in SO. And countless others around the internet.

Comment: Hi Gameiswar, I tried submitting as text but had problems formatting. what I am looking to do is to convert

Comment: So post your sample data as insert statements to a temp table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: your requirement is unclear , can you provide a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use `cross apply` combined with `for xml path('')` for this purpose:

```
  select distinct t1.Id, t3.EmailAddress 
  from TABLE t1
  cross apply (select t2.EmailAddress+'    ' 
               from TABLE t2 
               where t2.Id=t1.Id for xml path('')
              ) t3 (EmailAddress)
  order by t1.Id
```